# Cannot upload files with scp, but with pscp it works

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty, scp

I can login to a remote server with a login, which has a private key. This private key is without any password. When using `PuTTy` on Windows, I can login to that remote server without problems given that private key. Using `pscp` on Windows with this key also works without any problems.

But when using `scp` from linux with that same key, it seems not to work. The last messages from `scp` are these

```
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /path/to/key/id_rsa_download2.ppk
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
```

Permission denied, please try again.
    debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
    debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).

I am calling `pscp` with these parameters

```
pscp -r -v -l username -i /path/to/key/id_rsa_download2.ppk -P port C:\some\local\dir username@remoteserver:/remote/dir
```

And I am calling `scp` with these parameters

```
scp -r -v -i /path/to/key/id_rsa_download2.ppk -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -P port /some/local/dir username@remoteserver:/remote/dir
```

Can someone give me any hints where the problem is?

**Edit**
When I try to call the `scp` command in command line, then `scp` asks me for a password, but the key should not ask me for a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.ppk` file is a ***Putty*** private key file, it's not an OpenSSH key file.  See [What difference between openssh key and putty key?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74545/what-difference-between-openssh-key-and-putty-key)

From the `scp` messages you posted:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /path/to/key/id_rsa_download2.ppk
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
```

OpenSSH can't parse the key file you provided.